# Firebase snapshot has child equal to string

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code:

```
DataService.ds.MSGS_DB_REF_KEY1.queryOrdered(byChild: "livelli").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        for _ in snapshot.children{
            if snapshot.hasChild((self.textField.text?.lowercased())!){
                DataService.ds.MSGS_DB_REF_LIVELLO1.queryOrdered(byChild: "livello1").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot1) in

                    self.lvls = []

                    if let snapshot1 = snapshot1.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                        for snap in snapshot1 {
                            if let postDict = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            let level = Levels(levelId: snap.key, levelData: postDict)
                            self.lvls.append(level)
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            })
```

What I would like to do, is to check if the child name, that in my code is equal to the text field, contain one word of string that I write in text field. I have a database that is structured like:

Mydata -> keywords -> keywordlist1 ->   name:"level one",   value:"level one" (and other strings).

When in text field I write like "I want a random level" I would like to make app recognize the presence of the word "level" in the child name "level one". But with my code, the string is recognized only if it's equal to the name in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to directly query part of the name of a child. You could download all the children and then search through them in the client, but that's cumbersome at best and not a great option. A better option is to use a Cloud Function to search the database from the back end. Check out [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fulltext-search) and [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

Comment: ok I'm gonna try this now, thank you, for other complications, could I ask you other things? @Jen Person

Comment: Definitely! Unless you're editing your current question, just post any other questions separately. I check through any questions tagged with firebase. If you've never used Cloud Functions before, check out this video to see how to get started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ&t=3s

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life!

Comment: One more thing, can I check if in database is there the string I write in a text field? With the ".contains" @Jen Person

Comment: ".contains" will not check the database because it's a method called on an array object, so it would only work for data you've downloaded. https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2297359-contains

Comment: Could I write you in the chat? I need some help @Jen Person

Comment: Go ahead and read through the documentation for Cloud Functions and learn about Algolia first. See if you can try out some of the sample Functions on GitHub. If you're still stuck after that, then I'd be glad to chat.

Comment: yeah tomorrow I'm at school early so when I can I will study all, thanks. @Jen Person